# Show multiple lists in a container with sencha touch 2.1.0

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

**Descriptions:**

1. I have a view with a container named 'topContainer'.The items of the container consists of  a titlebar and a container named 'mainContainer'.
2. The container 'mainContainer' is vertically scrollable and its items consists of a panel called 'titlepanel',a button named 'btn1' ,a list named 'list1',a button named 'btn2' ,a list named 'list2',a button named 'btn3' ,a list named 'list3',a button named 'btn4' ,a list named 'list4',a fieldset with textareafield named 'input'.
3. The buttons are used to toggle a show/hide effect of the list next to each of them.And i want all of the lists show at first and the lists stretch full height of its data config(That is ,if the data has one item,the list takes up the height of one item;if the data has three items,the list will take up the height of three items).
4. All the list disables scroll(That's why i make the container 'mainContainer'  vertically scrollable).

**My problems:**

1. The lists will show only when flex config be set,so the the height of the list will not stretch to the height of the data it has.
2. The `scrollable:false` config of list dose not work.The `scrollable:{disabled:true}` will work.
3. The container 'mainContainer' dose not stretch to the actual height but always to the fullscreen height,but i want a long container enough to display all the data in the lists.

Comment: Don't post a description of your code, post the code!

Comment: Gabriel, have you solved this? If not, please post your code as Evan suggests.

Comment: @fractious  Actually,we did not choose this solution.Thanks all!